# Is there anything unusual with System.Windows.Forms.PowerStatus class in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I recently came across with `PowerStatus` class in `C#` and I got something unusual (I guess it IS, maybe it's because I don't know the platform or the language enough, you tell me!) When I want to create an instance I got the error:

> Error 1   The type 'System.Windows.Forms.PowerStatus' has no constructors defined C:\Users\Amin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication15\ConsoleApplication15\Program.cs    38  33  ConsoleApplication15

I double-checked the declaration through msdn which was:

> public class PowerStatus

Thus, it was not an `abstract` class. The question is, is it really possible to declare a class with absolutely and logically no constructor in `C#`?

Comment: Yes it is possible. In the case of a static class, there does not need to be a constructor because there will never be an instance of that class. In the case of a class who's constructor is private (perhaps using the Singleton pattern), it may exist but you won't have access to it by design.

Comment: you have access to it via: `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PowerStatus`.  Values are loaded into it via PInvoke

Comment: It has only got an `internal` constructor: see the class at ReferenceSource.Microsoft.com [(link)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PowerStatus.cs.html) (you have to scroll down past the `enum`s).

Comment: @GojiraDeMonstah Yes that's right. But the error I get both from IntelliSense and the compiler is not the same as when I use those techniques you said. For example when I set the constructor access modifier to private, it says '* is inaccessible due to its protection level'

Comment: @Plutonix Would you please explain it more?

Comment: @WaiHaLee Yes. According to that fact, I myself just have tested that approach by making the constructor internal in a DLL but I got no error!?

Comment: you dont create an instance of it, the Type is a Property on `System.Information`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing which is special about it is that it is used as a property on `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation`.  *You* do not create an instance of it, NET creates it as part of that larger class.

You can use the class to create a reference to just that part of `SystemInformation` which is pretty large:

```
PowerStatus ps = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;

Console.WriteLine(" Charge Status: {0}", 
                     ps.BatteryChargeStatus.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("     Full Life: {0}", 
                     ps.BatteryFullLifetime.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Life Remaining: {0}",
                     ps.BatteryLifeRemaining.ToString());
```